# Assigning a function to a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

```
function abc(){
    //multiple variables and functions
    a:function(){alert("a")};
}
function test(){
    var k=abc();
    k.a();
}
```

In the above case, I have a huge function abc() to be assigned to a variable. I want to call the member functions that are visible, like a() from the variable. Is this possible to implement and please give me a sample code if so.

Comment: Wait...what is the "a:function()" part? That doesn't seem to compile, unless it's some ES6 thing I haven't heard about.

Comment: @Katana314 it looks like OP has truncated out relevant bits of code (such as most of an _Object Literal_)

Comment: When you invoke `abc`, what does it `return`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm… contrary to @krillgar's answer, I believe you were expecting your `abc()` to return new object. Something like this:

```
function abc(){
    var privateVar;
    return {
    //multiple variables and functions
    a:function(){alert("a")}
    }
}
function test(){
    var k=abc();
    k.a();
}
```

Comment: Good catch. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 7):

When you include the parenthesis after your function, you're assigning the **result** of the function to your variable.

If you want to assign the function itself, just omit the parenthesis:

```
var k = abc;
k.a();
```

**EDIT**

Per @Kuba Wyrostek's answer, and @Pointy's comment, that `a()` function won't be properly exposed.

You'll need to take a look at the [Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html). What you need to do is to assign a function to a variable, and have that function return the functions that you want to be able to use outside of that function. This helps with *encapsulation*.

It's a little hard to tell from your code in the comment exactly what is the user-generated code, but I'll do my best.

```
var abc = (function () {
    var grabApi,
        initialize;

    // Just an example of how to assign an existing function
    // to a property that will be exposed.
    grabApi = SCORM2004_GrabAPI();

    // This is an example of how to have a property that will be
    // exposed be a custom function passing a parameter.
    initialize = function(initString) {
        return SCORM2004_GrabAPI().Initialize(initString);
    };

    return {
        getApi: grabApi,
        init: initialize
    }
}());
```

You can then use this `abc` object like this throughout your code. Again, this is trying to give an example of how to do what I think you're trying to do based on your comment.

```
// Assign the SCORM2004_GrabAPI function to a variable.
var SCORM2004_objAPI = abc.getApi();

// Call the Initialize function with an empty string.
abc.init("");
```

Comment: This is true, but it should be noted that a function called "a" declared locally inside function "abc" will *not* be available external to "abc" as a property of the function object.

Comment: SCORM2004_objAPI=SCORM2004_GrabAPI(); strResult = SCORM2004_objAPI.Initialize(""); This is a software generated code. Here I need write the SCORM2004_GrabAPI() and return the object in such a way that the user can access the SCORM2004_objAPI.Initialize("");. I don't understand how exactly I could implement it.

Comment: Thanks for that catch, @Pointy. I didn't think all the way through that. I'll update and put a nod to Kuba's answer as well.

Comment: @Whoophee I've updated my answer to include some more detail, and hopefully help you understand how to do what I think you're trying to do. The whole "software generated code" part is throwing me a bit, though I do understand how much more complicated that can make your question. Hopefully this will help you understand better.

Answer (score 0):

You should make it an object. In this way you can access its property `a`.

```
var abc ={
    a:function(){alert("a")}
}
function test(){
    var k=abc;//Ofcrse remove the parenthesis 
    k.a();
}
test();
```